# How do I delete an answer that is locked?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, historical-lock

I'd like to withdraw my answer from a question by deleting it. The answer is locked so I can't access it. In addition, the flag button is grayed out so I can't raise a flag to have it deleted.

How do I delete an answer that is locked?

Comment: We can flag posts with ordinary lock. No flag option means historical lock which is special.

Comment: No idea why this is being downvoted; it;s perfectly reasonable question asking for help with a non-obvious part of the network's functionality.

Comment: @Ben - I have lots of fans across the Stack Exchange network. My stuff gets down voted for me just posting. Another case in point is the [request on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293517/608639). Its a support request and its being down voted. How do you down vote a support request (as opposed to something marked discuss)??? So much for using the site correctly :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's locked and can't be flagged, your only recourse would be to bring it up on the appropriate per-site Meta or, if it's on this site, here.

Make your case for why it should be deleted and the reason you can't flag it.

It may be more appropriate for the answer to be disassociated from your account than deleted.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The question does not appear to be well received. I guess the community is saying it will not help future visitors.  I'm going to delete since its not helpful rather than accepting the answer.

Comment: Chat can fit as well, and less intrusive. :)

Comment: Now related: [How to get a support request fulfilled on Meta Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256031/173448)