# How to get a support request fulfilled on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, locked-answers

Well, the folks on Meta.SO managed to close a support request as off-topic: [Please delete an answer that is locked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293517/608639). In fact, the folks on Meta.SE told me to go there and make the request: [How do I delete an answer that is locked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256026/173448)

I don't understand why a support request would be marked as off-topic with the reason *"this question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community"*. It makes no sense to me since its a support request, and not a community discussion, like for a feature request.

I seem to be doing something wrong. How do I go about getting a support request fulfilled for Stack Overflow?

Should I make another request? If so, how do I ask it differently but acheive the same request?

Comment: You should take a break from SE for a bit. It's a better option than adding fifteen more meta quesitons within the next three hours.

Comment: Sorry about that @Won't. If everyone followed the rules (which are fairly loose at SE), then we would not have these problems.

Comment: I haven't seen anybody not following the rules.  What I have seen are a bunch of people who disagree with this or that.

Comment: I would call closing a support question as off-topic retribution. I think that would qualify as *"not following the rules"*. For what its worth, I try to follow the rules and not do things in retribution. For example, I despise the [Tags in title policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190). But look at my history and how many times I apply it even though I argued against it and despise it.

Answer (score 10):

Support request means asking for support with **one of the site features**. It does not directly mean asking for personal help with a specific post.

It can be used for such requests and personally I have no problem with that, but can see why others are not accepting this, since that's what we have flags for.

If you can't flag a specific post, flag other post and explain that you're talking about other post that you can't flag.

Anyway, to answer the original question: you can't force anyone to fullfil your requests. Just be patient, and if needed keep explaining.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the site cannot be forced to fulfill the request. The Close was clearly retribution. Is there anything that can be done, or will a blind eye be turned?

Comment: You can cast a Reopen vote or edit to explain why it's not a dupe, both will send the question to Reopen review queue - if 5 others will agree they can reopen it. Oh, that's exactly what happened a minute ago. :)

Comment: And a friendly tip: edits like the one you did there are NOT the correct way, they'll only draw negative attention and of course be rolled back.

Comment: Public humiliation is the only tool we have when the site implicitly condones that type of behavior. As for the negative attention, its not like it could be down voted any more than it already is... -10 is the same as -50 or -1000.

Comment: Yes it can, and it can cause the question to get locked and eventually if you keep doing those things on purpose, it can lead to your suspension. Your call.

Comment: @jww. If people don't like your question, just move on.

Comment: @Patrick - its not a question. Its a request to take action because I cannot.

Comment: Then get 1-1 with a mod.

Answer (score -2):

You're right. Support questions shouldn't be closed as off-topic. It's one of the problems with our system, that when someone doesn't like a support question they will sometimes vote to close it.

Whether or not your referenced question should be deleted, your Meta question is a valid support question.

Comment: Perhaps the site should add some controls to enforce the business logic. Its seems the site cannot control its mob.

Comment: Also see [What is the purpose of having tags if they are not honored?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256116/173448)